# Emulate 3 Button Mouse not working on Satellite laptop

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

The **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** feature doesn't work as described. **ALT+LMB** causes the entire Blender window to resize and then move in tandem with the motion applied to the mouse-pad. Is there any additional setting beyond clicking the Emulate 3 Button Mouse box that must be set correctly in order for this feature to work?

@Sybren

A. When you say, "conflicting keyboard shortcut," do you mean a shortcut in Blender itself, or something universal I may have done with my laptop? I have not intentionally set up ANY shortcuts yet in Blender.

B. If I understand you correctly, the Blender window does indeed resize itself and move whenever I use **ALT+LMB**, regardless whether **Emulate 3 Button Mouse** is checked or unchecked. There is another checkbox directly below Emulate 3 Button Mouse named, **Continuous Grab**. The problem also remains the same regardless whether Continuous Grab is checked or unchecked.

C. I don't know what **ALT-Drag** is. I am running Ubuntu on a Satellite laptop.

Comment: You probably set up a conflicting keyboard shortcut... If you disable emulated 3 button, does the blender window move?

Comment: Alt+drag is probably a window manager feature. Try turning it off, or switching hotkeys (I use super/win for the same)

Comment: I bought a 3 button trackball and forgot about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because Alt+LMB is the Ubuntu/Linux shortcut to move a window around. You may be able to circumvent this by using *super*+alt+LMB depending on your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *File -> User Preferences -> Input -> 3D View -> 3DView(global) -> Rotate View*

When you've found rotate view you can see what it's set to. I changed my rotate view to "keyboard" and <kbd>R</kbd>.

Every time I press "r" and use the mouse, my view rotates as it should.

(using the Steam version of Blender on ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Neat trick. It seems to only work on selected objects though, not the entire scene. Still, good to know.

Comment: @quazipseudo That's because R is the default hotkey for rotating objects, not the view. You'll have to set it to something else than R in order to work properly. Spencer Jones might have just set their hotkey for rotating objects to something different. Thus they can use R to rotate the view.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks :D